# Change default display of the Ubuntu screen

Tags: xorg

Currently I am working on a customize device (just like [tablet](http://www.ubuntu.com/tablet))  which has Ubuntu 12.10. Now I have to restructure the screen of that device. I have added sample design of the screen. We are getting this screen when we start the device.

How can I achive this. I know for this I have make changes in many configuration files of ubuntu. 
But I don't know how to start and in which files I have to make changes.

So that I need some guidelines for this? and we are using lightdm as display manager.

**Terminology**

**Internet connection message** - If I connect to internet using LAN then we have to show connection establised image

**logo**  - it just a logo

**online/offline** - if system is online on the server then we have to show green circle (like skype or facebook online option) else display red circle for offline.

**camera** - We have a camera for capturing the video

**Edit**

Also we are using [Awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/) framework window manager for X-server.

Feel free to ask me any question and sorry for bad english.
[image]

Comment: The terminologies you have used are very vague: what logo do you want? what is "internet connection message" and how is it different from "online/offline"? What camera are you talking about? Finally, 12.10 is no more supported :/

Comment: @Jobin I have edited my post can look into it and thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean because it's really hard to understand. What do you mean by **customize device which has Ubuntu 12.10** ? You installed Ubuntu on some device like tablet or phone? Or you installed Ubuntu on a pc desktop and you're just looking for the widgets/indicators to customize your desktop? Or you're trying to create your own widgets?

Comment: yes it is device just like tablet.

Comment: so you're trying to create your own widgets?

Comment: yes I am trying to create.

Answer (score 0):

If you can install *Kubuntu* (or *kde*) it's enough to put  [some `widget`](http://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Plasmoids). There's exists a big number of them, to keep a picture, to see internet connection speed, weather...

Comment: There's no need in installing `KDE` as `Unity` has tons of widgets/indicators.

Comment: @JohnnyEnglish  Never said he need to install... neither that is the only solution.
But I agree with you that he can be more detailed :)

Comment: I didn't mean he needs either... **need** in my comment used as a noun not a verb. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use *conky* to display everything you've listed except camera. If you want detailed information head over to *arch wiki*.